# Change mouse cursor when hover on plot item

Tags: hover, flot, mouse-cursor

I am wondering what is the best way to change mouse cursor when hovering on a plot item, and change cursor back to default one when away from plot item

```
plot.bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
            if(item) {
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    } else {
                            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    }
 }
```

It works in the beginning, however, doesn't work after pan plot...

Answer (score 7):

You're very close. Your second cursor set line is incorrent. Here's a corrected version:

```
plot.bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
    if(item) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } else {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you direct to a different page the cursor setting is preserved as pointer. Instead use the flotcontainer itself to set the cursor style.

```
$("#flotcontainer").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
  if(item)
    $("#flotcontainer").css("cursor","pointer","important");
  else
    $("#flotcontainer").css("cursor","default", "important");
});
```

Comment: The 'important' usually won't be necessary, and to clear the cursor afterwards you should use an empty string rather than 'default', so as not to override any other styles there might be in the container.